# Android- can't add SVG to navigation drawer icon

Tags: android, svg

I was playing around with the Navigation Drawer Activity template that Android offers when creating a new project. I am trying to change the default icons with SVG files using the Vector Asset importer. Unfortunately, I have been getting three errors randomly, sometimes Android Studio throwes an error and doesn't compiling, and sometimes compiles with no problem:
`(path/to/picture.svg) Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png`
 Or sometimes:
`Can't determine type for tag '<metadata> Svg Vector Icons : http://www.onlinewebfonts.com/icon '`
And when I delete that line:
`Can't determine type for tag '<g><g transform="translate(0.000000,512.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"> <path d="M5587.5,..."/></g></g>'`

I move the SVGs from `drawable` to a folder I named `icons` and sometimes that help, and sometimes it doesn't. I have tried everything (except the solution) to no avail.

This is the whole SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Svg Vector Icons : http://www.onlinewebfonts.com/icon -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve">
<metadata> Svg Vector Icons : http://www.onlinewebfonts.com/icon </metadata>
<g><g transform="translate(0.000000,512.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"><path d="M5587.5,4894.5c-146-401.3-510.8-1463.3-507-1467.1c3.8-3.8,130.6,188.2,282.3,426.3c151.7,238.1,282.3,435.9,290,441.7c7.7,3.8,80.6-151.7,163.2-347.6c82.6-195.9,155.5-355.3,161.3-355.3s213.2,142.1,460.9,314.9s455.1,311.1,457,307.2c3.8-1.9-28.8-182.4-73-401.3c-44.2-217-76.8-401.3-71.1-405.2c5.8-5.8,261.2,26.9,568.4,73c307.3,46.1,558.8,80.6,558.8,74.9s-172.8-176.7-386-382.1c-211.2-205.5-378.3-380.2-368.7-387.9c7.7-9.6,201.6-90.3,428.2-182.4c226.6-92.2,416.7-170.9,420.6-172.8c3.8-3.8-205.5-113.3-466.6-243.9c-259.2-128.7-472.4-240-470.5-245.8c0-5.8,182.4-169,403.3-364.9c222.8-194,393.7-357.2,380.2-362.9c-11.5-3.8-299.6-74.9-639.5-157.5c-338-80.6-603-149.8-587.6-149.8c44.2-3.8,1837.7,111.4,1954.9,124.8l101.8,11.5l-601,403.3c-330.3,222.7-608.7,410.9-616.4,418.6c-9.6,7.7,330.3,128.7,752.8,270.8c422.5,142.1,762.3,263.1,754.7,268.8c-7.7,7.7-295.7,111.4-641.4,230.4c-345.7,121-629.9,222.8-629.9,228.5c0,5.8,247.7,303.4,547.3,660.6c301.5,357.2,543.4,654.8,539.6,658.7c-3.8,3.8-389.8-96-856.4-224.7c-466.6-128.7-854.5-230.4-862.2-226.6c-7.7,3.8,30.7,174.7,88.3,380.2c178.6,654.8,213.1,787.3,207.4,787.3c-3.8,0-276.5-213.2-606.8-472.4c-585.7-459-601.1-470.5-622.2-426.3c-13.4,25-117.1,261.2-230.4,524.2c-113.3,265-213.1,487.7-220.8,495.4C5643.2,5027,5614.4,4971.3,5587.5,4894.5z"/><path d="M1061.4,4754.3c0-5.8,218.9-270.8,485.8-589.5c664.4-798.8,1323.1-1599.6,1607.3-1954.9c259.2-326.5,336-464.7,410.9-747c63.4-234.3,71.1-313,76.8-760.4c5.8-453.2,25-531.9,155.5-675.9c163.2-184.4,458.9-261.2,710.5-188.2c149.8,42.2,499.3,218.9,700.9,351.4c290,192,641.4,570.3,965.9,1040.8c149.8,218.9,194,324.5,224.7,533.8c28.8,192,3.8,368.7-76.8,537.7c-115.2,245.8-301.5,361-685.6,424.4c-528.1,88.3-637.5,174.7-1885.7,1515.1L3264,4763.9H2161.7C1556.8,4763.9,1061.4,4760.1,1061.4,4754.3z"/><path d="M6434.4,493.2c-161.3-57.6-311.1-147.9-604.9-368.7c-280.4-211.2-618.3-389.8-985.1-516.6c-142.1-49.9-307.2-115.2-364.9-144c-339.9-170.9-539.6-435.9-512.7-675.9c32.7-268.8,305.3-537.7,833.4-816.1c314.9-167.1,405.2-282.3,457-583.8c51.8-305.3,111.4-1081.1,136.3-1799.3L5407-4780h825.7h823.8l-11.5,274.6c-7.7,149.8-15.4,783.5-15.4,1405.7c0,1342.3-15.4,1215.5,257.3,2208.3c30.7,115.2,36.5,178.6,28.8,432.1c-5.8,195.9-21.1,336.1-42.3,412.9C7137.2,439.4,6833.8,633.3,6434.4,493.2z"/><path d="M3953.4-1851.6c-128.7-126.7-119.1-234.3,55.7-604.9c65.3-142.1,130.6-305.3,142.1-361c13.4-65.3,21.1-428.2,21.1-1031.2V-4780h172.8h172.8l-1.9,265c-1.9,144-7.7,457-15.4,695.1c-5.8,238.1-5.8,579.9,1.9,760.4l15.4,328.4l105.6,218.9c57.6,121,105.6,232.3,105.6,249.6c0,21.1-73,74.9-197.8,147.8c-109.5,63.4-259.2,163.2-332.2,222.8c-73,59.5-142.1,107.5-155.5,107.5C4030.2-1784.3,3989.9-1815.1,3953.4-1851.6z"/></g></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Use vector drawables, not SVG. You need to import it in Android Studio.

Comment: @Nicolas Not vector assets? I have already tried "Import Drawables" in the Resource Manager and did not have success. What format should I download them from the internet in? Will I have to get different resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> New -> Vector Asset in (Android Studio)
Provide Path of your .svg android studio will covert your .svg to vector

Comment: That is precisely when I get all of the errors, as it says in the question.

Comment: is there any animation in that svg? if so them remove content like metadeta and tranformations You can do animations using other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Android Vector Assets only support a subset of SVG. If it's not super complex, you can try hand-editing your SVG to remove the parts that aren't compatible (in your case, possibly the metadata, and the transformations). Translations and scaling can be performed in other ways, anyway. Try leaving only the path tag within the svg tag.